# Replacing a TextBox with a DropDownList in InsertItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, formview

I thought this would be easy and straightforward, but I seem to be having an issue with it.

Basically, I have this in a formview:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="StatusTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Status") %>' />
```

And I want to replace it with this:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="StatusDropdown" runat="server">
       <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="A">Active</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="I">Inactive</asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>
```

I'm not exactly sure how to bind this like the Textbox is bound.

Is there a straightforward answer?

Comment: just put that frop down in your template field....it will work..what you want to bind

Comment: It won't work as is, there's no binding going on. I guess what I'm asking here is, is there a way to bind data in the aspx page?

Comment: Codebehind is not a hack, actually it's best practise since you have full control and compiler support.

Comment: Tim, totally agree. Just the solutions I've seen for this particular example appear to be hacks.

Comment: you want to bind data in your dropdownlist

Comment: @CaptainSkyhawk you have only two items so why you want to bind it..i mean i can not understand what exactly you want to do with your drop down list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codebehind is not a hack, actually it's best practise since you have full control and compiler support (shows errors at compile time and avoids careless mistakes)

For example (assuming that the `DropDownList` is in the `EditItemTemplate`):

```
private void FormView1_DataBound(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    switch (FormView1.CurrentMode)
    {
        case FormViewMode.ReadOnly:
            break;
        case FormViewMode.Edit:
            // note that the DataSource might be a different type
            DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)FormView1.DataSource;
            DropDownList StatusDropdown = (DropDownList)FormView1.FindControl("StatusDropdown");
            // you can also add the ListItems programmatcially via Items.Add
            StatusDropdown.DataSource = getAllStatus(); // a sample method that returns the datasource
            StatusDropdown.DataTextField = "Status";
            StatusDropdown.DataValueField = "StatusID";
            StatusDropdown.DataBind();
            StatusDropdown.SelectedValue = drv["StatusID"].ToString();
            break;
        case FormViewMode.Insert:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind it to the SelectedValue property as so:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="StatusDropdown" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Status") %>'>
```

The value in status has to match the value of a drop down list item.